# How to play multiple Animations using AnimatorSet?

Tags: java, animation, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I'm using `Sceneform` to create an android app that plays animation. I'm trying to start multiple Animators sequentially using `AnimatorSet`. The code works perfectly when trying to play two animations, but whenever I add a 3rd animation, the first two animations play then the app crashes.

Here's a piece of the code:

```java
    List<Animator> animatorList = new ArrayList<Animator>();

    AnimationData ad1 = JimRenderable.getAnimationData("Abm_09|A");

    Animator a = new ModelAnimator(ad1, JimRenderable);
    animatorList.add(a);

    AnimationData ad2 = JimRenderable.getAnimationData("Abm_09|B");

    a = new ModelAnimator(ad2, JimRenderable);
    animatorList.add(a);

    AnimationData ad3 = JimRenderable.getAnimationData("Abm_09|C");

    a = new ModelAnimator(ad3, JimRenderable);
    animatorList.add(a);

    AnimatorSet as= new AnimatorSet();
    as.playSequentially(animatorList);
    as.start();
```

How can I let it play more than just 2 animations?

Answer (score 0):

> **`AnimatorSet`** public class, which extends `Animator` class, provides a mechanism to group animations together so that they run in relation to one another. You can set animations to play **simultaneously**, **sequentially**, or **after a specified delay**.

*Here's how your code should look like*:

```
AnimatorSet bouncer = new AnimatorSet();

bouncer.play(bounceAnim).before(squashAnim1);

// THESE FOUR ANIMATIONS PLAY SIMULTANEOUSLY
bouncer.play(squashAnim1).with(squashAnim2);
bouncer.play(squashAnim1).with(stretchAnim1);
bouncer.play(squashAnim1).with(stretchAnim2);

bouncer.play(bounceBackAnim).after(stretchAnim2);

ValueAnimator fadeAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(newBall, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
fadeAnim.setDuration(250);
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.play(bouncer).before(fadeAnim);

animatorSet.start();
```

> In this code `squashAnim1` clip plays simultaneously with `squashAnim2`, `stretchAnim1`, and `stretchAnim2`.

And this example explains how it works: we set up an `AnimatorSet` to play:

- `anim1` and `anim2` at the same time,
- `anim3` to play when `anim2` finishes,
- and `anim4` to play when `anim3` finishes:

  ```
  AnimatorSet clips = new AnimatorSet();
  clips.play(anim1).with(anim2);
  clips.play(anim2).before(anim3);
  clips.play(anim4).after(anim3);
  ```

Also, you might use `Animation listeners`. They can listen for important events during an animation's duration. Here's a code how it looks like:

```
ValueAnimator fadeAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(newBall, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
fadeAnim.setDuration(250);

fadeAnim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        balls.remove(((ObjectAnimator)animation).getTarget());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to use .play() and .with()/after but the same problem keeps happening. Two animations play sequentially just fine. But whenever I add a third animation the program plays the first two then crashes.

Comment: Try not to use arrays. Use each clip as a separate element.

Comment: Tried that. Still the same result. I made 3 Animator objects a1, a2, a3. Then I used:
 as.playSequentially(a1,a2,a3);
 The program crashes after playing a1 and a2. I also tried using:
as.play(a1).before(a2);
as.play(a2).before(a3);
Still got the same result.
I can't seem to find the problem. It doesn't really make sense how 2 animations play but a third one causes the app to crash.

Comment: I think it's not AnimatorSet()'s fault. There's an error. You need to debug it somehow.