# AnimatorSet - Getting Error: Only one ModelAnimator may play on a ModelRenderable at a time

Tags: android, android-animation, arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to play multiple animations one after another, but I can't seem to get it to work. It's giving me the error:

```
Only one ModelAnimator may play on a ModelRenderable at a time
```

I've followed the instructions from this Stackoverflow Answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684795/11110509

```
private void animateModel(ModelRenderable modelRenderable) {

        AnimationData danceData = modelRenderable.getAnimationData("Armature|Pecking.002");
        ModelAnimator modelAnimator = new ModelAnimator(danceData, modelRenderable);

        AnimationData danceData2 = modelRenderable.getAnimationData("Armature|Walking");
        ModelAnimator modelAnimator2 = new ModelAnimator(danceData2, modelRenderable);


        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.play(modelAnimator).before(modelAnimator2);
        animatorSet.start();


    }
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, since 1.16, ModelAnimator and ModelRenderable.getAnimationData are not supported anymore.

If you must use version less than 1.16,

```
   List<Animator> animatorList = new ArrayList();
   animatorList.add(modelAnimator);
   animatorList.add(modelAnimator2);
   animatorSet.playSequentially(animatorList);
   animatorSet.start();
```

You can do like above.
I haven't tested the code since i am using sceneform 1.16.